# How to add new item in collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to add a new item in collection:

```
$collection->prepend("Name", 0);
```

But it does not work for collection structure [image]

Full code is:

```
$cities = City::where("country_id", $id)->get();
$cities = Helper::firstEmptyValue($cities);


public static function firstEmptyValue($collection)
{

return $collection = $collection->prepend("Name", 0);
}
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @SFSFSFSF you need to show us what your expected output is so we can help you.

Comment: I expect to see item in `#items: array:1 [2 => "Brazil"]`

Answer (score 0):

`$collection->prepend("Name", 0)` adds the item to the beginning of the collection.

If you want to add it to the end, use the `push` method:

```
$collection->push('Name');
```

Comment: Look please question again